# Eclipse shortcut not working (Android string extracting)

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm wondering why a shortcut combo Alt+Shift+A, S does not work (S at the end is needed because of a conflict with another shortcuts). After Alt+Shift+A the options dialog appears, but after clicking S nothing happens. It's annoying to use the mouse for such an operation so I would love to have a solution. The other questions I've looked for didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here - http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/custom-eclipse-shortcuts-import-export/ . Define the shortcut yourself, if it conflicts with another.

Comment: That is a default shortcut in the Eclipse for Android build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the string highlighted first.  Once it is highlighted, performing the shortcut `Alt+Shift+A;S` should bring up the prompt for extracting an Android String.  You can also use `Ctrl+1`, and then choose the option from that menu.